# when defining a table in SequelizeJs its name is changed when executing

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

when defining a table in SequelizeJs its name is changed when executing resulting in a ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE.

This is my code :

```
var API_TOKEN=database.sequelize.define('API_TOKENS',{
     user_id:{
        type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
     },
     token:{
        type:Sequelize.STRING
     }
});
```

and the error :

Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'tableName.API_TOKENs' doesn't exist

Note:notice how the table name is changed when executed , i am using mysql database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of two available options that can be put in the `options` of [`sequelize.define`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#definemodelname-attributes-options-model) method

- `freezeTableName`
- `tableName`

According to the sequelize documentation (concerning how it names the database table basing on model definition)

> By default, sequelize will automatically transform all passed model names (first parameter of define) into plural.

By using the `freezeTableName`, the database table will be named exactly the same as your model name. On the other hand, if you want fully custom table name, you should use the `tableName` attribute.